# Multi Threading in a Tree like structure

Tags: multithreading, data-structures

Below is the Question I was asked in an interview and I believe there are many solutions to this question but I want to know what can be the best solution (and stackoverflow is perfect for this :) ).

Q: We have a tree like structure and have three threads. Now we have to perform three operations: Insert, Delete and lookup. How will you design this?

My Approach: I will take mutex for insert and delete operation as I want only one thread to perform at a time insert or delete. While in case of lookup I will allow all the three threads to enter in the function but keep a count(counting semaphore) so that insert and delete operation can't be perform this time.
Similarly when insert or delete operation is going no thread is allowed to do lookup, same with the case for insert and delete.

Now he cross questioned me that as I am allowing only one thread at a time to insert so if two nodes on different leaf need to be inserted then still my approach will allow one at a time, this made be stuck.

Is my approach fine ?
What can be other approaches ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about like this? Similar to a traffic road block(broken paths).

- Each node will have two flags say `leftClear_f` and `rightClear_f` indicating `clear-path` ahead
- There will be only one MutEx for the tree

**Lookup Operation:**

- If flags are set indicating path ahead is under modification, got to `conditional_wait` and wait for signal.
- after getting signal check the flag and continue.

**Insert Operation**

- follow the `Lookup` till you get to the location of insertion.
- acquire MutEx and set relevant flag of `parent_node` and  both `child_node`s after checking their state.
- Release the MutEx so that parallel `Delete`/`Insert` can happen on other valid unbroken paths
- Acquire MutEx after insert operation and update the relevant flag in the `parent_node` and `child_node`s.

**Delete Operation**
same as Insert operation except that it deletes nodes.

PS: You can also maintain the details of the nodes under `Insert` or `Delete` process someplace else. Other operation can jump the broken paths if necessary/needed! It sounds complicated yet doable.

Comment: Thanks :)..This sounds reasonable..one quick doubt "acquire MutEx and set relevant flag of parent_node and both child_nodes after checking their state" why both child nodes, why not only parents either left flag or right flag set depend on where insert need to be done ?

Comment: It helps in traversing. If traversing in a given order is not required then chuck setting flags in children.

Comment: One last doubt suddenly strikes me, if insert need to be done at leaf node then as per your logic we are locking leaf flag and its parent flag and then inserting below the leaf ...or locking the leaf will work ?